# Google Tag firing even when filter does not match

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am trying to configure a trigger such that it does fire on the home-page but it does fire on the home-page as well:-

[this is the trigger configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99pI5.png)

[following is from the preview mode, the trigger fire even when the filter is false...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvikQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your condition to

`does not end with .com/`

You are missing a trailing `/`. When the user is on your home page the `Page URL` will resolve to `http://www.yoursite.com/`